# How do I update a field (mySQL) from my HTML table...

Tags: mysql

I have an HTML table showing my mySQL database.

I frequently need to change the content in the "current" field, which is the last column, adding and subtracting.  The current number for any is "0".  I would like to click on a cell and update the number by either adding or subtracting from the current number in the field.

I would prefer to click on the cell and be prompted with a popup dialogue to add or subtract to that particular cell (field).

Here is my link:  http://www.logicpkg.com/login.htm
Login: admin
Password: demo

I need help and I've come so far.

Thank you.

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default) for the dialog box and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s ajax functions to update the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to put an onclick javascript event on the cell and pop up a dialogue box. Based on user input, set a hidden field with that value and do a submit(). Update your database and redisplay the page.